# How do I adjust position of a text inside a Bootstrap panel with overriden max-height?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cannot seem to figure out how to move the text inside a panel-body whose max-height I have adjusted. Below are the code snippets of my html and the overrides I did.

HTML :

```
    <div class="row chatListRow">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body userBox">
                <small>User 1</small>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.chatListRow{
  margin-bottom: -1.5em;
  margin-top: -1em;
}

.userBox{
  max-height:1.5em;
}
```

This is what it looks like :
[image]

What I want to do is to adjust the position of the text, like move it to the top a little bit so that the text still looks vertically centered. I have no idea how to adjust the position of the text inside the small tag. Thanks for anyone who would be willing to help me out.

So what I did was to adjust the padding of userBox.

```
.userBox {
  max-height: 1.5em;
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-top: 0.5em;
}
```

And this is how it now looks like:
[image]

Thanks to Joseph Marikle for helping me out!

Comment: what adjustments are you wanting?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question more.

Comment: Hello, I added some clarifications in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well... It's more like you set a height on an element that forces the padding to also be calculated in with the height. `1.5em` is inclusive of the default padding.  You can fix this of course by setting the `box-sizing` to `content-box`.  By default all elements are set to `border-box` in twitter bootstrap (it's litterally `* { box-sizing: border-box; }` with vendor prefixes thrown in).  so, just set it to `content-box` for `.userBox`.

```css
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */
body {
  padding: 3em;
}

.chatListRow{
  margin-bottom: -1.5em;
  margin-top: -1em;
}

.userBox{
  max-height:1.5em;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row chatListRow">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-body userBox">
        <small>User 1</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining but this did not solve my problem out though I was able to understand about box-sizing. I apologize for my vague question. I edited it out and maybe you could help me out? Cheers!

Comment: @dtem052996 It is what's causing your issue even still. The reason why it's so low is that you there is by default a 15px top and bottom padding for a total of 30px.  If you have a font size of 16px or whatever, and a max height of 1.5em, that translates to a total max height of 14 + 7 or 21px.  Because the padding alone takes up more than that, your content area is reduced to 0px tall.

Comment: The solution (if you still want a maximum of 1.5em in height) is to reduce the padding.  That's why it's not behaving as you would expect.  You could even set top and bottom padding to 0 and have 1.5 line-height if your text content never breaks to the next line.

Comment: Thanks! Adjusting the padding solved the problem. I did not really change the body's padding as it will affect my other elements but what I did was to change userBox's padding-top and padding-bottom.